# Dúvida - Php com file iput

Tags: php, html, arquivo, sistema-de-arquivos

Boa tarde,

Eu tenho um formulário na qual é feito o upload de uma imagem, quando é feito o upload eu recebo a foto
conforme array abaixo, no php ele cria um arquivo temporário no caso **tmp_name**.

Eu preciso mostrar a foto desse arquivo temporário, porque o formulário é invalidado então a imagem fica ainda no **tmp_name**, ou seja mostra a foto guardada nesse arquivo temporário, e minha dúvida é como eu acesso esse arquivo temporário mostrando a imagem ?

Eu já tentei fazer tpm_name concatenando com nome **tmp_name . / . name**,
porem não traz essa é minha dúvida qual forma de consumir esse arquivo temporário é possível?

```
'foto' => array(
        'name' => 'brasao_1548090804.jpg',
        'type' => 'image/jpeg',
        'tmp_name' => 'C:\xampp\tmp\phpAAF9.tmp',
        'error' => (int) 0,
        'size' => (int) 74954
)
```

Comment: Para exibir o arquivo, você precisa antes movê-lo para um local acessível publicamente. O diretório temporário não é público

Comment: deu certo vlw...

Comment: Você diz isso pra salvar o arquivo da imagem ou pra mostra na mesma hora que o usuario insere no input?

Answer (score 0):

Objetivo esperado: quando o usuário faz upload de uma imagem e da submit no form a imagem some do input e o usuário precisa fazer upload novamente.

O que foi feito.

Eu criei uma nova pasta temporária **CONDUTOR_TEMP** e quando feito upload no input eu movi a foto para um diretório temporário e se houvesse validação no formulario eu consumo a imagem enviada para o diretorio temporário:

```
move_uploaded_file($['foto']['tmp_name'], **CONDUTOR_TEMP** . DS . $['foto']['name']);
```

Depois que movido eu copio a imagem e joga ela na pasta original

```
copy(CONDUTOR_TEMP . DS . $['foto_visualizacao'], CONDUTOR . DS . $['foto_visualizacao']);
```

Código final:

```
$condutorFoto = $this->request->data['Condutor']['foto'];
            if (!empty($condutorFoto) && !empty($this->request->data['Condutor']['foto']['tmp_name'])) {
                if($this->request->data['Condutor']['foto_movida'] != 'Sim'){
                    move_uploaded_file($this->request->data['Condutor']['foto']['tmp_name'], CONDUTOR_TEMP . DS . $this->request->data['Condutor']['foto']['name']);
                    copy(CONDUTOR_TEMP . DS . $this->request->data['Condutor']['foto']['name'], CONDUTOR . DS . $this->request->data['Condutor']['foto']['name']);
                  
                    $this->request->data['Condutor']['foto_visualizacao']  = $this->request->data['Condutor']['foto']['name'];
                    $this->request->data['Condutor']['foto_movida'] = 'Sim';
                }
```